# Remove specific rectangles from a ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How I can remove specific rectangles from this ArrayList ? 
I want to remove the rectangles that are higher than 100.

```
ArrayList <Rectangle> array = new ArrayList <Rectangle> ();
for (int i = 0; i<array.size(); i++) {
     if (array.get(i).getHeight() < 100) {
            array.remove(i);
     }
}
```

This code don't work !
If you look after the elements, there are fewer rectangles but there are still those higher than 100 !

Comment: Your `if` condition is incorrect, it should be `array.get(i).getHeight() > 100`

Comment: You can change  '<' to this '>'

Comment: Add System.out.println at various points and find out whats happening :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about Java 8 solution?

```
array = array.stream().filter(r -> r.getHeight() <= 100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It returns a new `List` of `Rectangle`s that are higher than `100`.

Comment: I assume you wanted to assign the resulting List somewhere otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Yes, sure. I assigned the result to the same variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the simple typo of `>` vs `<`:

If you iterate the list forwards and remove elements by index, you will miss out elements if there are two adjacent items which meet the criteria for removal.

Either:

- Iterate the list in reverse:

  ```
  for (int i = array.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  ```
- Decrement `i` after removing an item (generally not recommended, as it is confusing to alter a for loop's iteration variable in the loop body):

  ```
  array.remove(i--);
  ```
- Use an `Iterator`:

  ```
  Iterator<Rectangle> it = array.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Rectangle r = it.next();
    if (some condition) {
      it.remove();
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Whoever it was - thanks for the edit. I removed the "edit..." bit at the bottom, as it was a straightforward typo.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your if condition as below

```
ArrayList <Rectangle> array = new ArrayList <Rectangle> ();
for (int i = 0; i<array.size(); i++) {
     if (array.get(i).getHeight() > 100) {
            array.remove(i--); // "--" means go back one step
     }
}
```

Comment: Note: you need to do `array.remove(i--);` as the index of the next entry has changed.

Comment: A for-each loop is hard to use if you are modifying the collection.